# how to find sum of series defined by the following relation T(n+2) = (Tn+1)^2 + T(n) where T(0)=0 and T(1)=1 in C language

Tags: c, algorithm

********** for n<=10**********

Some output may even exceed the range of 64 bit integer.
how to find sum of series defined by the following relation

*T(n + 2) = (T(n + 1))<sup>2</sup> + T(n)*

where *T(0) = 0* and *T(1) = 1*

*yes it is t(n+1) square,,,my issue is how to store big numbers,,like calculate T(12) and try to store the result, it's result is beyond the range of long long int.

Comment: is it T(n + 1)^2? Also, it's not clear what your issue is. Is it because too large values, did you right anything to calculate this?

Comment: @Bathsheba it is, and I'm the engineer :D. No ambiguity because the statement makes no sense if you eval (n+1)² first

Comment: What's the largest value of `n` you need to consider?

Comment: If 128-bit are enough, you might try to go with gcc and `uint128_t` if it's supported on your platform

Comment: If the problem is about how to write code to find the values you're looking for, then the relation gives you code for a recursive implementation. If the problem is about finding a closed form for this expression, you would be better off on math.SE.

Comment: @G.Bach From the perspective of a programmer, this is a classical example for an iteration, not for a recursion

Comment: @Ctx You're right, that's way smarter here.

Comment: "it's result is beyond the range of long long int." does not add value to the post as `T(n)` growth is very rapid.  `T(9)` exceeds 75 bits.  `T(13)` is about 6.3e363.  `T(32)` exceeds 600000000 bits.  Without some limits on the range or precision of the desired answers, this post is too broad.  Too bad, it is an interesting question.

Comment: value of n is           n<=10

Answer (score 2):

For use with gcc on 64-bit machines, if 128-bit are enough:

```
typedef unsigned int uint128_t __attribute__((mode(TI)));

uint128_t T (int nr) {
     uint128_t t0=0,t1=1,t2,sum = 0;
     while (nr--) {
         t2 = t1*t1 + t0;
         t0 = t1;
         t1 = t2;
         sum += t2;
     }
     return sum;
}
```

Comment: semicolon after `sum += t2` :)

Comment: @mikedu95 Argh, fixed ;)

Comment: @Danh The builtin-type (if available) is `__uint128_t`, so this doesn't interfere

Comment: Using 64-bit math correctly calculates `T(0) ... T(8)`. Using non-standard `uint128_t` extends the range by 1 to  `T(0) ... T(9)`.

Comment: @chux That's not surprising, since taking a number to the square about doubles the bits its representation needs.

Answer (score 0):

You need a library that supports arbitrary precision numbers, like GMP for example: https://gmplib.org/

Comment: @egur et al: GMP *is* the answer. The link is to further information about GMP — what do you expect the author to do, include the source code to GMP here?

Answer (score 0):

Recursive solution:

```
some_big_int_type T(int N) 
{       
    if (N == 0) 
        return 0;
    if (N == 1)
        return 1;
    some_big_int_type Tpow2 = T(N - 1);
    return Tpow2 * Tpow2 + T(N - 2);
}
```

`big_type_int` may be `uint128_t`  as Ctx answer.

Comment: `Tpow2 * Tpow2 - T(N - 2) + T(N - 2);` (+ and semicolon). And this is just T(N), not the sum T(0) + ... T(N)

Comment: @mikedu95 I did not get anything ?!

Comment: In the line that contains the return, between Tpow2 * Tpow2 and T(N - 2), it should be a + instead of -. And you missed the semicolon at the end of that line. Also, this computes T(N) which is not the goal of this post. The value to be computed is T(0) + T(1) + ... + T(N) for a given N.

Comment: You are right about - and about simicolon